# How can I wrap elements on mobile screen sizes?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want to have the sponsored text and image wrap to the bottom of the logo on mobile but flex-wrap does not seem to be doing it.  I would like the 50x50 image and the 'sponsored by" text to go underneath the 80x80 image below 1024px (side by side). Thanks

```js
console.clear();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>


<div class="inline-block relative bottom-2 right-1">
  <span class="inline-flex items-center text-blue">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/80x80"/>
   
    <div class="flex justify-center text-black">
      <div class="mt-2 ml-0.5 sm:text-sm text-[10px] flex-wrap lg:flex">sponsored by</div>
      <img class="mt-0.25 pl-0.5 object-scale-down flex-wrap lg:flex" src="https://placehold.co/50x50" />
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex-wrap applies to the children of the element on which it's applied, so you need to move that class. This would result in the elements wrapping *when there's not enough space*. This demo shows that.

If you want to wrap at a particular breakpoint instead you need to use something like a block-level wrapper for small screens and transition to inline-block for larger screens.

```js
console.clear();
```

```css
.mobile {
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<h2 class="mb-2">Full Width</h2>

<div class="inline-block_disabled relative bottom-2 right-1">
  <span class="inline-flex items-center text-blue">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/80x80"/>
   
    <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-center text-black">
      <div class="mt-2 ml-0.5 sm:text-sm text-[10px] lg:flex">sponsored by</div>
      <img class="mt-0.25 pl-0.5 object-scale-down lg:flex" src="https://placehold.co/50x50" />
    </div>
  </span>
</div>

<h2 class="mb-2">Mobile Width</h2>

<div class="inline-block_disabled relative bottom-2 right-1 mobile">
  <span class="inline-flex items-center text-blue flex-wrap ">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/80x80"/>
   
    <div class="flex justify-center text-black">
      <div class="mt-2 ml-0.5 sm:text-sm text-[10px] lg:flex">sponsored by</div>
      <img class="mt-0.25 pl-0.5 object-scale-down lg:flex" src="https://placehold.co/50x50" />
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I added the `flex-wrap` class to the outer span element to enable flex wrapping for smaller screens. Additionally, I modified the structure inside the span to use `flex-col` for mobile `(flex-col sm:flex-row)`, ensuring that the "sponsored by" text and the 50x50 image are displayed in a column layout on smaller screens and side-by-side on screens larger than 640px.

```js
console.clear();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="inline-block relative bottom-2 right-1">
  <span class="inline-flex items-center text-blue flex-wrap">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/80x80"/>

    <div class="flex flex-col sm:flex-row items-center text-black">
      <div class="mt-2 sm:mt-0 sm:text-sm text-[10px]">sponsored 
      by</div>
      <img class="mt-0.25 pl-0.5 object-scale-down" 
      src="https://placehold.co/50x50" />
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do what was required. The trailing content never moves under the first image.